# Autohotkey Script To Open File With Picasa

Tags: windows, mac, autohotkey, photos, preview

I'm a completely noob when it comes to AutoHotkey scripts, the limit of my knoweldge is opening a folder with a key combination.

There's one Mac feature that I've always been envious of, the spacebar-to-open-a-file feature (I think it's called Preview). Is it possible to set up an AutoHotkey script to open a file with a certain program? Specifically, I'd like to be able to press ctrl+enter and open files with Picasa Photo Viewer (obviously this isn't quite as advanced as Preview, but most of what I want to preview are PSD files anyway).

The Photoviewer's exe is located here with a default install: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Picasa3\PicasaPhotoViewer.exe`

Thanks!

EDIT: I've found this, but it doesn't fit my needs entirely. I need to be able to have a file selected in Windows Explorer and just press ctrl+enter to open the selected file.

`Run, wordpad my.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoHotkey doesn't interface with Windows Explorer. However, we can use the clipboard to overcome this.

#### The script

```
^Enter::
    Backup := ClipboardAll
    Clipboard = 
    SendPlay, ^c
    ClipWait, 1
    Type := FileExist(Clipboard)
    If Type = A
        Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Picasa3\PicasaPhotoViewer.exe" %Clipboard%
    Clipboard := Backup
return
```

#### Hot it works

- `^Enter:: ... return` specifies the hotkey, where `^` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and Enter is <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

  If it's pressed, `...` gets executed.
- `Backup := ClipboardAll` backs up all data stored in the clipboard (`All` also includes non-text data like, e.g., screenshots).
- `Clipboard =` clears the clipboard, so we can check when something gets copied to it.
- `SendPlay, ^c` simulates pressing the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy the current file to the clipboard.

  As a result, the variable `Clipboard` now hold the file's name.
- `ClipWait, 1` waits for up to one second for the clipboard to contain any data.
- `Type := FileExist(Clipboard)` and `If Type = A` check if the clipboard's content points to an actual file.
- `Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Picasa3\PicasaPhotoViewer.exe" %Clipboard%` opens the selected file in Picasa.
- `Clipboard := Backup`  restores the inital clipboard data.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, cursor flashes to loading for a split second, then nothing happens. Entering a similar command in to the command prompt does work, though, so obviously you can launch files with PhotoViewer in that method.

Comment: Still nothing. Tried it with Notepad instead and I'm getting an error "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Comment: I'm just selecting one.

Comment: I get "MsgBox, %clipboard%" (probably because I copied that line of code). If I copy the image, then press ctrL+Enter I get the path of the file. Copying the file manually, then pressing ctrl+enter opens the file, so it appears to be an issue when copying the file.

Comment: Just getting a blank message box now.

Comment: Ah! Tweaked the lastest edit a bit, remove teh Type and If type,  changed SendPlay to send and it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it works now! The `Type` and `If Type` shouldn't have anything to do with it. It's definitely the `SendPlay`that's not performing as it's supposed to. I wonder why... Be careful that `Send` can cause some unexpected interactions when running multiple AHK scripts at once.